# Empty sequence when interacting with TimeSpan in a list

Tags: c#, ienumerable

So here's the thing. I have the following list:

```
var Diffusions = new List<SetDiffusion>();
```

Filled this way:

```
Diffusions.Add(new SetDiffusion 
{ 
    VideoName = videoName, 
    Selected_Dif = ConvertToTimespan(TimeParts[1]) 
});
```

`VideoName` being a string, and `Selected_Dif` a Timespan.

Now with said list I need to get the closest absolute Timespan and call a method with it and its corresponding `VideoName`. Now this is my first time messing around with a class list but from what I understand this should work:

```
UpcomingDif = Diffusions.OfType<TimeSpan>()
                        .OrderBy(t => Math.Abs((t - DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay).Ticks))
                        .First();
```

I've used it with a previous `List<Timespan>` without `.OfType` and it worked fine. But now in the same testing environment, it raises an empty sequence error.

Any idea what's wrong with my code?

Thank you.

**LAST EDIT:**

Just in case it might help someone, here is my timer initialization (Thanks @Koopakiller):

```
        var diffusion= Diffusions.OrderBy(t => Math.Abs((t.Selected_Dif - DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay).Ticks)).First();
        TimeLeft = diffusion.Selected_Dif - DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
```

Comment: I presume its due to the `OfType` call which returns an empty sequence? As SetDiffusion is not of type `TimeSpan` ?

Comment: @DanielVarab Yes that was it, I wasn't familiar with `list<object>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Diffusions` does not contain any `TimeSpan` that's why `OfType` does not return any element from the list.

The simpliest way to do your task is to order the elements by there time stamp descending and then take the first.

```
UpcomingDif = Diffusion.OrderByDescending(t => t.Selected_Dif)
                       .First()
```

`UpcomingDif` is now a `SetDifusion`. If you want only the time span to now, you can access the `Selected_Dif`property and subtracting `DateTime.Now` with it:

```
var timeSpan = DateTime.Now - UpcomingDif.Selected_Dif;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However wouldn't proceeding this way result in a negative timespan since `UpcomingDif` is the "earliest" timespan instead of the closest to `DateTime.Now` ?